# html redirect issue

Tags: html, redirect

I am using the following simple javascript for redirection. However, it works in some machine but not others. Does anybody know why? Is there a better way to make sure every machine works? I also tried `<meta>` redirect it has the same issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://mypage.html#instruction"
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: `window.location.href = ...` // at least use valid code :-)

Comment: http://mypage.html#instruction is probably just an example url but, if not, try using a valid relative path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normally use the `href` property of `location`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/mypage.html#instruction"
//-->
</script>
```

Are you getting any javascript errors?

Answer (score 2):

you can also try to use [location.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp) method to load new url.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because your URL is wrong and some browsers are being generous?  `http://mypage.html#instruction` is probably not the URL you want.  Perhaps just `mypage.html#instruction` without the `http://` or maybe `/path/mypage.html` if it's on the same server, or `http://server.name.com/mypage.html#instruction`.

As a fallback, you should probably include HTML like

```
Please <a href="http://server.com/mypage.html#instruction">click here</a>
```

for browsers that just don't run the script for whatever reason.

Comment: +1 One should also use a regular hyperlink as a fallback to conform with best practices.

Answer (score 1):

The most compatible way to do this is with a [Meta refresh.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)

You just put this into your HTML HEAD tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://example.com/" />
```

I don't know why they say it is deprecated/discouraged, since it has been supported for many years and does not require any Javascript. It is discouraged because of usability, but that's another concern.